# Is there an "idiomatic" opinion on using a function versus a method for doing an operation on an object in go?

Tags: go

There are two ways to accomplish modifying an object (well, value) in Golang:

```
type Node struct {
    Name    string
}

// First way
func SetName(node *Node) {
    node.Name = "something else"
}

// Second Way
func (node *Node) SetName() {
    node.Name = "something else"
}
```

Is this purely semantics/opinion based or is there a reason one is better than the other (more "idiomatic")? Or perhaps both are valid in different use cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a method for the type `Node`, that type now implements the interface `interface { SetName() }`. This does not happen if you define a function.

If this is important, use a method. If not, you can use either.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the interface implications as mentioned by Burak, I would ask the following question:

Is the behaviour `SetName()` characteristic of the `Node` type's identity?  In other words, does adding this as a method to the type's method list enhance the meaning of the type, or is it just cluttering the method list with a procedure that happens to act on this type?

Comment: So my actual use case, was each node has a client that connects to its own database. What I don't like, is I have a method "writeToDatabase" for my Node type, that writes data. Something about this feels wrong. Almost like the node should not be responsible for this, but rather something like a utils function that takes an interface with a write method. Not sure if that makes sense or not.

Comment: @AdamJohnston if I'm understanding you, you may want a pattern where you have types such as `Node` that have a method to return a data object which is destined for a database, and then a utility function that takes one (or more) of these objects, reads the data objects from them, and then writes them to the database.